# flutter slidable one slide at a time when we tap on list item

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to slide when tap on the list item , when i tap on 1st time slider opens and for the second time when i tap on  another list item 1st slider just closes , second slider not opening .

Here is the code

```
    Slidable(
      groupTag: '0',
      enabled: enable,
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      key: _globalKey,
      endActionPane: ActionPane(  motion: ScrollMotion(),extentRatio: 1,children: [_getSwipeActions(context)],),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
       
          return InkWell(
            onTap:(){
              if( Slidable.of(context).actionPaneType==ActionPaneType.none){
                Slidable.of(context).close();
              }
              else{
                Slidable.of(context).openEndActionPane();
              }
            },
            child: ListItem(data,
              ,context),
          );
        }
      ),)
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing need to do soo much, just assign a same groupTag to all of your slidables like bellow and read the below text for better understanding.**

You will have to set the same groupTag value to all the Slidables that share the same group and add a SlidableAutoCloseBehavior above your Slidables.

In the snippet below, the first two Slidables have the same group, so only one of them can be open, while the last Slidable is independent of the others.

```
    SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      Slidable(
        groupTag: '0',
      ),
      Slidable(
        groupTag: '0',
      ),
      Slidable(
        groupTag: '1',
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Slidable(
      groupTag: '0',
      enabled: enable,
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      key: _globalKey,
      endActionPane: ActionPane(  motion: ScrollMotion(),extentRatio: 1,children: [_getSwipeActions(context)],),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
       
          return InkWell(
            onTap:(){
              if(Slidable.of(context).actionPaneType.value==ActionPaneType.end){
                Slidable.of(context).close();
              }
              else{
                Slidable.of(context).openEndActionPane();
              }
            },
            child: ListItem(data,
              ,context),
          );
        }
      ),)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to how this code addresses the issue. At first, I couldn't see any difference between this and the OP's original code. Then, on careful inspection I found the added `.value` in this line: `if(Slidable.of(context).actionPaneType.value==ActionPaneType.end){`. You need to highlight that and explain how/why it fixes the problem.